# Merging 2 dataframes with only few same items

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm looking for merging 2 dataframes with items and some numbers. Let's pretend 1st column is the name, 2nd is how much money the name gets and the 3rd is how many hours they worked. And I'm looking for merging them in a way I'll show you in the example. Hopefully it is going to be all clear. I didn't try anything special here, I guess there should be a function which is going to make it in a spectacular way.

Thank you guys!

1st Dataframe

```
name  money hours 
------------------
name0 1234  50
name1 4321  50
name2 1234  40
name3 1234  50
name4 4321  50
name5 1234  40
name6 1234  50
name7 4321  50
name8 1234  40
```

2nd Dataframe

```
name  money hours 
------------------
name1 200   4
name4 100   5
name6 300   6
name7 300   10
name8 400   14
name1 100   10
name7 200   5
name7 100   3
```

OUTPUT should look like this:

```
name  money hours 
------------------
name0 1234  50
name1 4621  64
name2 1234  40
name3 1234  50
name4 4421  55
name5 1234  40
name6 1534  56
name7 4921  68
name8 1634  54
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is really a `merge` since you have duplicate names that you need to aggregate. This looks like a `concat` + `groupby` + `sum`

---

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('name', as_index=False).sum()
```

```
    name  money  hours
0  name0   1234     50
1  name1   4621     64
2  name2   1234     40
3  name3   1234     50
4  name4   4421     55
5  name5   1234     40
6  name6   1534     56
7  name7   4921     68
8  name8   1634     54
```

Comment: Hello, Mr. User. Gorgeous! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

try like below

```
df3 = df2.groupby('name',as_index=False).sum()
result = df1.merge(df3, on='name', how='left')
result['hours']=result.hours_x+result.hours_y.fillna(0)
result['money']=result.money_x+result.money_y.fillna(0)
```

Comment: Hi, didnt really tried bcs users answer was a oneliner which i like, but thanks for responding! :)